# Authors: User field type not installed?

Tags: solspace-user

I might misunderstand something here - so sorry in advance if this is a dumb question.

We have purchased User and installed it on a clean install of EE2:

- EE 2.11.1
- User 3.5.3 for EE 2.x

I am not working on a prototype for a required custom functionality using Related. This is what the documentation has to say:

*To create a Related Authors field, you must select a custom fieldtype of User with the sub field of Related Authors.*

I presume this is a channel custom field type? It seems not to be available as a *field type* when I try to add it as a custom field.

When checking Add-Ons --> Fieldtypes, User is not on the list (neither with status *Installed* nor *Not Installed*).

I checked the module preferences and do not see a specific setting that I have missed.

What am I doing wrong? Is Related Authors only available in User 4.x?

ED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things were a little bit backwards for User in EE 2.x. Also, the instructions you're looking at are for User 4.x for ExpressionEngine 3. You need to reference the [documentation for User 3.x when using ExpressionEngine 2](https://solspace.com/legacy_docs/user_3/multiple_authors/).

To create the User Authors "fieldtype", you need to:

1. Go to Preferences tab in User module control panel area
2. At bottom of page, enter a name for the "tab" to add to the publish page where User Authors "field" will be
3. Submit/save page

You don't have to keep your User Authors field in that tab either. You can simply visit the Publish page and edit the layout to have the User Authors "field" on your main tab and remove the User Authors "tab" from the layout. :)